# Python Game Image File Structure

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently creating a python pygame and am in the process of naming my images in the game.

For example: a game titled `"Hello World"` might contain image assets such as coins and a background.

The image files corresponding to these two assets could be named `"HW_coin"` or `"HW_background"`, but I do not believe that these names are very conventional. As more assets are added, I believe that this type of naming conventions may make determining which image belongs to what asset.

Could I get advice on file structure/naming conventions for the files.

Comment: Any image name is fine as long as it is consistent and readable. If you have multiple projects, put them in separate folders so the images don't get mixed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the best way to manage these sorts of game assets is to sort them into embedded folders.

First, I start with a general `images` folder.

Next, I would make other folders such as `backgrounds`, `collectables`, and `character`.

You can then embed more folders within those if needed, such as if you have multiple characters.

The file structure looks like the following:

> - images
>
>   - backgrounds
>
>     - …
>   - characters
>
>     - player1
>
>       - ...
>     - player2
>
>       - ...
>   - collectables
>
>     - ...

In regards to the individual names of the files, naming them `HW_...` is not very good. It's **repetitive** and if all files started with `HW_` you might as well remove that completely.

This is where the file structure listed above becomes important. By creating directories to house these specific assets, we can remove the prefixes to each of the files such as `HW_`

An example of this is instead of naming a file `HW_Background_FirstWorld` you could store the file in `/HelloWorldGame/Images/Backgrounds/FirstWorld/` and then name the file whatever you'd like. If it's a sunny background, you could name it `Sunny` and because of the directory it's stored in, you'll know what the sunny background is used for.

Comment: Thank you! I have improved my file names now.

Comment: @LMCuber No worries! If you found it helpful, you can mark this answer correct. By doing so, you will help other stack overflow members easily find the answer to questions similar to this.

Comment: @lime I applaud how determined you were when editing the awkwardly written question ;)

Comment: @Neuron Anything for that sweet, sweet S.O. karma